# How to create a drop-down in asp.net core MVC from another Model with validation?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, dropdown

**Model Class.cs**

```
public class Class
    {
        public int ClassId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string EncryptedId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Class Name")]
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Model Subject.cs**

```
public class Subject
    {
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string EncryptedId { get; set; }
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        public int ClassId { get; set; }
        public Class Class { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel CreateSubjectViewModel.cs**

```
public class CreateSubjectViewModel
    {
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string EncryptedId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Subject Name")]
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }

        public int ClassId { get; set; }

        public int ClassesId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateSubject()
{

    List<Class> classList = _context.Classes.ToList();
    ViewData["classList"] = classList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.EncryptedId, Text = x.ClassName });
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateSubject(CreateSubjectViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Subject newSubject = new Subject
        {
            //SubjectName = model.SubjectName,
            //here code for store data in subject table
        };
        _cdsRepository.AddSubject(newSubject);
        return RedirectToAction("ListClasses", "UDP");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

How can I get data from `Class.cs` and show in **drop-down** with proper validation of **drop-down** on button click.

If everything is OK, then store data in `Subject.cs` with **Class Id** value.